# Is there a way to parse and label line by line contact information using SAS or R?

Tags: r, sas

I have scraped a few webpages that has contact information. I would like to prefix label to corresponding contact info lines; like Name, Address 1...n, and Country.

Actual info:

```
ABC Inc.

Sam Iselin

101 Jim Street

Suite 212

Royal Park, IL, 60302

United States
```

---

Expected outcome:

```
Company: ABC Inc.

Name: Sam Iselin

Address 1: 101 Jim Street

Address 2: Suite 212

Address 3: Royal Park, IL, 60302

Country: United States
```

Comment: a little bit overkill to use SAS for that. Better go with perl or python.

Comment: Please clarify if there will always be 6 lines per contact (no more, no less) and always in the same order, or do the contents have to be examined to determine which details are being presented. If the latter then please clarify the rules, as, for example, a company name could contain a country name, or a country name could be abbreviated, etc.

Comment: Does *scraped* mean that information is now in a text file that has to be read into a SAS data set via `input`?

Comment: @ Amir Yes, there are addressess that has only one address line, and some two but none more than 3 lines of addresses. And there are no company names that have country names or abbreviated country names.

Comment: @ Richard, yes the scraped info is already in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the order of entries is always the same:

```
text="ABC Inc.

Sam Iselin

101 Jim Street

Suite 212

Royal Park, IL, 60302

United States"

parsed_tbl <- cbind(c("Company:","Name:","Address 1:","Address 2:","Address 3:", "Country:"),str_split(text,"\n\n")[[1]])

parsed_str <- paste(apply(parsed_tbl,1,paste,collapse=" "),collapse="\n\n")

cat(parsed_str)

   Company: ABC Inc.

   Name: Sam Iselin

   Address 1: 101 Jim Street

   Address 2: Suite 212

   Address 3: Royal Park, IL, 60302

   Country: United States
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments, that the data will always be in the given order and Address lines can range from 1 to 3 .. following code can be used

```
data have;
infile 'Y:\my progs\csv_ipfiles\scraped.txt';
input all_data &$50.;
run;

proc sql noprint;
select count(*) into :max_obs from have;
quit;

data want;
length mod_data $60.;
set have;
if _n_=1 then mod_data=catx(": ","Company",all_data);
else if _n_=2 then mod_data=catx(": ","Name",all_data);
else if _n_=&max_obs then mod_data=catx(": ","Country",all_data);
else 
do;
    number=_n_-2;
    mod_data="Address "||number||": "||all_data;
end;
drop all_data number;
run; 

proc print data=want; run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` statement can be coded using the `(variable-list) (informat-list)` construct to input each line of data for each of your 6 variables.  The data must have 6 lines of data per 'record' in order to have success with this technique.

Example:

```
* make a fake scrape;
filename scrape temp;
data _null_;
  file scrape;
  put 
"ABC Inc." /
"Abel Anderson" /
"18 Andover St" /
"Suite A" /
"Annapolis, MD 12345"/
"United States" /
"XYZ Inc." /
"Xavier Xalionton" /
"18 Exacto Lane" /
"Suite 3" /
"Xephyrton, NM 55455"/
"United States"
;

filename out "C:\temp\scrape-labeled.txt";
data _null_;
  infile scrape truncover;
*   file out;              * send output to log for now, uncomment to send to file;

  array field $200 field1-field6; * array 6 pdv variables corresponding to a single record;
  attrib                         /* label values will be used for output */
    field1 label="Company:"
    field2 label="Name:"
    field3 label="Address 1:"
    field4 label="Address 2:"
    field5 label="Address 3:"
    field6 label="Country:"
  ;

  input (field(*)) ($CHAR200. /) @;     * read in 6 lines to the arrayed variables all at once;

  do over field;                 * output <label> <value> of each variable;
    rowheader = vlabel(field);   * label already has the : in it;
    rowdata = vvalue(field);
    put rowheader rowdata;
  end;
run;
```

If the field 'names' that prefaced the data were 'normal' SAS names with no embedded spaces and allowed a `=` instead of `:`, the output could be made with a single `put` statement that also incorporated a variable-list.

```
put (field(*)) (=/);
```